# Error while building my application after installing automapper and mapping

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I am trying to build the my application after mapping I get the below Error.

The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

error CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0.

I tried to resolve the issue following above provided links but did not overcome the issue. I am getting error in App_Start/MappingProfile.cs

```
public class MappingProfile:Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerDto, Customer>();
    }
}
```

Can this error be because of automapper version 4.1.1 which is installed locally?

Comment: It says that you need to install  "assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0.", meaning, you are adding a library that is not supported with your current version of .net standard. Please check, the supported version of that library you currently installed.